# Fetch user posts from linkedln

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have a requirement to get user's LinkedIn post to my mobile app. I do some research on google and setup an app in LinkedIn developer portal. I got this api after search which I believe give access to user post. But while accessing this API, I'm getting error. Could you please help me out to find how can I get the user's post in my mobile app and what permission needs to request in portal for this?

REQUEST: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3A&q=author&count=1
In header:
LinkedIn-Version:202301
Authorization:
X-Restli-Protocol-Version:2.0.0 RESPONSE:
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-author /posts",
"status": 403
}

I would be very thankful to you for your support.

Comment: Have you requested access to, and been approved for, the permissions needed to use the Posts API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: @Ashavan Could you please help me out which product permission i need to requested on linkedln portal is it  "Advertising API".

Comment: According to the documentation tree on the left side of the page, the Posts API falls under the Community Management API.

Comment: As per the link provided by you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http#permissions
"r_member_social" permission required which is restricted.
But in the "Community Management API"  "r_member_social" is not presented.
Can you please confirm can we fetch user posts without enabling "r_member_social" permission.

Comment: I do think that permission is needed, but you'll need to contact LinkedIn to be sure.